# symfony 2.3 passing path id to checkbox form in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I have a problem that has been bugging me for days now, and I know it might be trivial for some but please bear with me. In my twig I have an **href** that reveals a modal with a checkbox, the **href** also contains a path to an action in my controller

**Twig**

```
<a href="{{ path('delete_image', {'id':image.id}) }}" data-reveal-id="deleteModal" class="icon-edit" style="position:absolute;"></a>
```

**Action in Controller**

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/delete", name="delete_image")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, CategoryImage $CategoryImage, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $CategoryImage = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:entity')->find($CategoryImage->getId());

            $em->remove($repo);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('page_main', array("id"=>$id)));
}
```

**Modal**

```
<div id="deleteModal" class="reveal-modal large">
    <h6>Delete Image</h6> 
        <br/>
        {{form_start(DeleteImageForm, {'attr': {'id': 'DeleteImageForm'}})}}
        Delete Image
             {{form_widget(DeleteImageForm.remove)}}
             {{form_errors(DeleteImageForm.remove)}}<br/><br/>
        admin password <br/>
            <input type="password" id="DeletePass"/>
        <br/>
            <button id = "Delete">Submit</button>
        {{form_end(DeleteImageForm)}}
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $('#Delete').on('click', function(e){

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    if ($('#DeletePass').val() == 'password'){ 
            $( "#DeleteImageForm" ).submit();
    }else{
            alert('invalid password');
            e.preventDefault();

        }
    });
```

Is there any way to pass the id / value of the path to the modal so when checkbox is checked and is submitted it goes to the action?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to pass / alter parameter to symfony route, dynamically from javascript?

Comment: Yes, that is my intention but I can't find anything over the net or maybe i'm just really bad at finding them @Jeet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate your delete form in twig, by passing a placeholder for the dynamic parameter i.e `id`. You can do it in controller where you generate the `deleteForm`.

The idea is to have a unique identifier in `action` so that we can replace via jQuery.

```
return $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('image_delete', array('id' => 'image_id')))
    ->setMethod('DELETE')
    ->getForm()
;
```

Now, when your modal gets open, Through `jQuery`, replace the placeholder i.e `image_id` to your required value, , as below :

```
var currentUrl = jQuery("form#DeleteImageForm").attr('action');
// suppose 154 is your new image id.
var newHref = currentUrl.replace('image_id', '154');
// change url of the form action.
jQuery("form#DeleteImageForm").attr('href', newHref);
```

Hope this helps.

Note : The code is not tested!

Comment: well the logic is there, so i'll accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: by the way, should I add something like a variable containing the path? i.e. **var route = "{{ path (etc.)}}"**

Comment: If you have `form` on page on page load, you don't need a variable, jQuery can read path from form `action`. If form not available, yes, you need to generate a path.

Comment: um quick question here, what if lets say I have 2 images and both of them have the icon that will reveal the same modal, how will I know what to put in the **newHref** depending on which of the 2 I click?

Comment: Write jQuery `onClick` event and bind the javascript code to replace parameter. So which ever image is being clicked.
You should store image `id` in your image tag and read it inside the jQuery event.